# get-culture returns wrong results when run in remote session

Tags: powershell

I want to check the number decimal separator on multiple machines use powershell. If I run `get-culture` in local powershell the result is correct. It will return English (UK) and correct number format, e.g. decimal separator '.'. But if I run the command remotely:

```
Invoke-Command  -ComputerName $server { (get-culture) }

Invoke-Command  -ComputerName $server { (get-culture).NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator}
```

The result is wrong. It returns German(Germany) which is the language of the machine where I invoked the command. Please help.

Comment: Just to add the machine I run the command is Windows Server 2019 and the remote machine is on Windows 11.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the **system** level culture settings with `Get-WinSystemLocale`

---

`Get-Culture` only returns the user-level culture setting, which any user can set. As you've found, Powershell remoting automatically applies your local culture in the session. You can specify a different `Culture` and/or `UICulture` by name using a `SessionOption`:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -SessionOption @{culture='en-gb'} -ScriptBlock {Get-Culture}
```

---

The culture of the current running powershell process, `$PSCulture`, is read-only and cannot be changed.

If you need your remote command to run using the correct culture for the remote system, you can check it before starting your session, like so:

```
# check the remote system culture before running script
$remoteCulture = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {Get-WinSystemLocale}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -SessionOption @{culture=$remoteCulture} -ScriptBlock {
  # some command that requires the remote culture
  Get-Culture
}
```

Or alternatively, set the culture for new threads/processes started from your session:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
  [system.threading.thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Get-WinSystemLocale
  Start-Job {Get-Culture} | Receive-Job -Wait
}
```

Comment: I worked around the issue by checking the registry instead. I think the problem is that the returned culture from this command belongs to Local System account instead of the current login account. By checking registry you can get both Local System and a specific user's settings.

Comment: @JadeMay can you add an answer with the keys you used?